# ASP.NET web app force an iframe to reload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, bootstrap-4

I'm not new to .NET Core development, but I am very new to ASP.NET Web Apps.

I have an Index.cshtml that has the following iframe in it:

```
    <iframe 
      height="800" 
      width="1300" 
      loading="eager" 
      frameBorder="0" 
      scrolling="no" 
      seamless="seamless" 
      allowtransparency="true" 
      src="https://example.com/?page_id=436" 
      title="My site" />
```

I need to force this iframe to reload (not from cache) whenever the page gets refreshed. On the web, I found the following suggestion:

```
iframe.src = "https://example.com/?page_id=436?reload="+(new Date()).getTime();
```

Here's my question: Where in a ASP.NET web app (using bootstrap) would I put this code to make it refresh my iframe? I'm somewhat familiar with javascript (haven't used it in a while), have very little knowledge of ASP.NET, and almost none of bootstrap. I know html/css pretty well.

I'm confused about where in the code to put this bit of javascript so that it will always run when I refresh the page. And I don't know how to make that code reference my specific iframe.

Thanks!

Comment: `<iframe>` [is not a self-closing element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe),  so you can't use `<iframe />`, instead you have to have a separate closing-tag: `<iframe></iframe>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify that the , as SNBS suggested, executed. But for some reason, it didn't do what it needed to do. So, then I got an idea! Why not use the C# code instead of javascript, so now my Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Example";
    string pageUrl = "https://example.com/?page_id=436?reload=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

<div id="site-main">
    <div>
        <h1 class="headline">Printing some good stuff here</h1>
        <p class="headline">And now some description!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe id="cgblog" height="800" width="1300" loading="eager" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" allowtransparency="true" src="@pageUrl" title="My site">
    </iframe>

</div>
```

The key was to define the variable pageUrl and then put that in the iframe's src. This works like a charm!

Comment: There is no `<iframe>` attribute `allowtransparency`, nor `seamless` (they were short-lived experiments around 2008-2010 and every browser has dropped support since then), while `frameBorder` and `scrolling` are obsolete (use CSS `border` and `overflow` instead - though `overflow` only works on same-origin iframes).

Comment: Thanks for that info! Most of my HTML knowledge is old, so that makes sense. I'll update the iframe accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code refreshes your `iframe`. If you want to refresh it when the page is refreshed, you should execute it after the page loads — in a defer script:

```html
<script defer>
  iframe.src = "https://example.com/?page_id=436?reload="+(new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work when I put it in my Index.cshtml. I think it might matter where it appears in the code. I'm new to boostrap, and so I don't know exactly how and when things get loaded.

Comment: Have you put it into the end of `body` (not into `head`)?

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I was having trouble doing that, as I have not yet gotten too used to navigating all the files in the bootstrap files in my web app project.